# Use Dropdowns with PayPal Subscriptions for 'A3' Parameter

Tags: html, paypal, e-commerce, subscriptions

I'm trying to do something like the following in order for the user to select their recurring subscription plan.

I keep getting the following error in PayPal when trying to submit this form:

*'Invalid Regular period. You must specify valid values for the A3, P3, and T3 parameters for a subscription.'*

I've specified the A3, P3, and T3 params in the form, so I'm not sure what's going on.  Can someone help?  Thanks in advance!

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<table>
<tr><td>Frequency</td></tr><tr><td>
<select name="a3">
                <option value="438.00">Every 2 weeks: $438.00 USD - monthly</option>
                <option value="219.00">Every 4 weeks: $219.00 USD - monthly</option>
                <option value="146.00">Every 6 weeks: $146.00 USD - monthly</option>
                <option value="109.50">Every 8 weeks: $109.50 USD - monthly</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Coffee Selection</td></tr><tr><td>
<select name="item_name"> 
                <option value="Ethiopian Ground Subscription">Ethiopian Ground</option>
                <option value="Colombian Ground Subscription">Colombian Ground</option>
                <option value="Colombian Whole Bean Subscription">Colombian Whole Bean</option>
                <option value="Guatemalan Ground Subscription">Guatemalan Ground</option>
                <option value="Guatemalan Whole Bean Subscription">Guatemalan Whole Bean</option>
                <option value="Decaf Ground Subscription">Decaf Ground</option>
                <option value="Decaf Whole Bean Subscription">Decaf Whole Bean</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@lifesongfororphans.org">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M"> <!-- billing cycle unit=month -->
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> <!-- billing cycle length -->
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"> <!-- recurring=yes -->
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1"> <!-- reattempt=yes -->
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.gobena.org">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.gobena.org">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Write them in capital letters in your code and see if it works.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<table>
<tr><td>Frequency</td></tr><tr><td>
<select name="A3">
                <option value="438.00">Every 2 weeks: $438.00 USD - monthly</option>
                <option value="219.00">Every 4 weeks: $219.00 USD - monthly</option>
                <option value="146.00">Every 6 weeks: $146.00 USD - monthly</option>
                <option value="109.50">Every 8 weeks: $109.50 USD - monthly</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Coffee Selection</td></tr><tr><td>
<select name="item_name"> 
                <option value="Ethiopian Ground Subscription">Ethiopian Ground</option>
                <option value="Colombian Ground Subscription">Colombian Ground</option>
                <option value="Colombian Whole Bean Subscription">Colombian Whole Bean</option>
                <option value="Guatemalan Ground Subscription">Guatemalan Ground</option>
                <option value="Guatemalan Whole Bean Subscription">Guatemalan Whole Bean</option>
                <option value="Decaf Ground Subscription">Decaf Ground</option>
                <option value="Decaf Whole Bean Subscription">Decaf Whole Bean</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@lifesongfororphans.org">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="T3" value="M"> <!-- billing cycle unit=month -->
<input type="hidden" name="P3" value="1"> <!-- billing cycle length -->
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"> <!-- recurring=yes -->
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1"> <!-- reattempt=yes -->
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.gobena.org">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.gobena.org">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: And replacing the '.' with a ','?

Comment: Nope.  No luck.  I've specified USD as the currency, so I would think that decimals would work fine.  I've even tried without decimals and with $ in the value attrib.

Comment: I know, I didn't think it'd work neither but had to check. Sorry my mistake, I did not find any obvious problem...

Comment: From [here](http://www.moneyscripts.net/forums/support/2010/03/26/paypal-error-invalid-regular-period) and the solution that worked, can you try to set T3 to 'D' and P3 to '30'?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14760/discussion-between-casey-and-frank-presencia-fandos)

Answer (score 0):

This code ended up working fine.  I was running into a caching issue, which is why I kept receiving the error.  :)